# How to make "Pretty" URL after dynamic content load using ajax

Tags: html, jquery, .htaccess, url

I am currently developing a website that will dynamically load the page content using ajax triggered by hash changes.

The code looks like this

```
        $("*").delegate("a", "click", function () {

            // Trigger Hash Change
            window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");

            return false;
        });

        $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {

            let newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

            $("#main-content").load(newHash + " #ajax-content", function (responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr) {

            }).hide().fadeIn();
        });
```

Basically what I am working on now is making the URL look "Pretty", I have modified the .htaccess file to remove the .html extension

So a URL that looks like this

> [www.example.com/about.html](http://www.example.com/about.html)

will become this

> [www.example.com/about](http://www.example.com/about)

If I navigate the index (home) "www.example.com" page of the website and then navigate from there to the about page, the URL looks fine. "www.example.com#about" since the server does not display the "index" in the URL.

However, if I navigate straight to the about page like this [www.example.com/about](http://www.example.com/about), then from the about page to another page, for example, the contact page. I get a URL that looks like this [www.example.com/about#contact](http://www.example.com/about#contact). When it should look like this [www.example.com#contact](http://www.example.com#contact).

My question is what is the best way to handle this? should I use jquery to redirect all to the index page and then add the hash to load the correct content? or is there some way I can not display the unnecessary part of the URL?

I hope my question was clear, I'm new to the server-side stuff involving the .htaccess file. FOr the ajax stuff I was following this tutorial from CSS tricks

> https://css-tricks.com/video-screencasts/85-best-practices-dynamic-content/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `history.pushState`

```js
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/new-url");
```

The url will be `www.example.com/new-url`

in fact you can get `history.state` after use this method.

```js
console.log(window.history.state)
```

output should be `"object or string"`

You can see the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

Remember to use `/` to override the entire path.

To do what i think that you want, you can just override the url to `/` and set the hash.

Comment: The problem with this is that it is then adding an unnecessary change to the history, so if the user decides to go back, they will have to press the back button twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the best way to do this, but I have managed to redirect any page to the home page and then replace the / with the hash value so that the site wont end up wit "messy" URLs.

```
    if(window.location.pathname != "/home.html")
    {
        window.location.replace("home.html" + window.location.pathname.replace("/", "#"));
    }
```

what happens id the user navigates to "*[www.example.com/about*"](http://www.example.com/about*%22) they will actually be sent to the homepage with the #about.html. So the never end up like this "*[www.example.com/about#about*"](http://www.example.com/about#about*%22)